# Multiple bash script with different parameters

Tags: bash

I have the following bash script, that I launch using the terminal.

```
dataset_dir='/home/super/datasets/Carpets_identification/data'
dest_dir='/home/super/datasets/Carpets_identification/augmented-data'

# if dest_dir does not exist -> create it
if [ ! -d ${dest_dir} ]; then
    mkdir ${dest_dir}
fi

# for all folder of the dataset
for folder in ${dataset_dir}/*; do

        curr_folder="${folder##*/}"
    echo "Processing $curr_folder category"

    # get all files
    for item in ${folder}/*; do


        # if the class dir in dest_dir does not exist -> create it
        if [ ! -d ${dest_dir}/${curr_folder} ]; then
            mkdir ${dest_dir}/${curr_folder}
        fi

        # for each file
        if [ -f ${item} ]; then
#            echo ${item}
            filename=$(basename "$item")
            extension="${filename##*.}"
            filename=`readlink -e ${item}`

            # get a certain number of patches
            for i in {1..100}
                do
                    python cropper.py ${filename} ${i} ${dest_dir}
                done
        fi
    done
done
```

Given that it needs at least an hour to process all the files.
What happens if I change the '100' with '1000' in the last for loop and launch another instance of the same script?

Will the first process count to 1000 or will continue to count to 100?

Comment: First one will count to 100 and the second will count to 1000.

Comment: Aside: You've got a whole lot of quoting bugs that http://shellcheck.net/ will catch.

Comment: Frankly, though, this is really, *really* inefficient. It's silly to spin up the Python runtime in a tight inner loop from shell, rather than just doing all your work from inside a single Python process.

Comment: BTW -- it's not at all clear what your title has to do with the question (in `1..100`, `100` *isn't a parameter*, but is a hardcoded value; trying to parameterize that value, one would run afoul of [BashPitfalls #33](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.7B1...24n.7D) unless one switched to a [c-style `for` loop](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/c_for)). In general, StackOverflow questions should be cut down to the barest minimum necessary to represent the core of the issue, problem or question, and given a title that's very closely related to that item.

Comment: ...so, if the core of the question is "what does `{1..100}` mean?", *ask that*, and take everything unrelated out.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy This is not a tight inner loop; the shell overhead here (including the cost to start a new Python interpreter) is minimal compared to the hour it takes for `cropper.py` to run.

Comment: @chepner, I took the "hour" to be total across all invocations, as opposed to per each.

Comment: Maybe you want to "parametrize" (pass on command line) your 1..100, so you can launch an instance for 1..100, another for 101..200 and so on?

Comment: ...if that's what the OP wants, then I gave them links to both the pertinent BashPitfalls page and the `cfor` bash-hackers wiki page -- but the question should be clarified to make that question clear, if they actually want an explicit *answer* for it as such.

Answer (score 0):

I think the file will be readonly when a bash process executes it. But you can force the change. The already running process will count to its original value, 100.

You have to take care about the results. You are writing in the same output directory and have to expect side effects.

Answer (score 0):

"When you make changes to your script, you make the changes on the disk(hard disk- the permanent storage); when you execute the script, the script is loaded to your memory(RAM).

(see https://askubuntu.com/questions/484111/can-i-modify-a-bash-script-sh-file-while-it-is-running  )

BUT "You'll notice that the file is being read in at 8KB increments, so Bash and other shells will likely not load a file in its entirety, rather they read them in in blocks."

(see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121013/how-does-linux-deal-with-shell-scripts )

So, in your case, all your script is loaded in the RAM memory by the script interpretor, and then executed. Meaning that if you change the value, then execute it again, the first instance will still have the "old" value.

Comment: BUT if you edit the file cropper.py , then obviously it is really likely that the change in your python script will affect the value of your previously executed bash script.